# Can one prove that the product rule depends on continuity of differentiable functions?

Tags: real-analysis

In calculus textbooks, the theorem asserting continuity of differentiable functions often appears just before the product rule.  The proof of the product rule usually says
\begin{align}
& \underbrace{\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)} h}_{\text{This}\to(fg)'(x)\text{ as }h\to0.} \\[12pt]
= {} & \overbrace{f(x+h)}^{\begin{smallmatrix}\text{This}\to f(x) \\ \text{ as }h\to0.\end{smallmatrix}}\ \ \overbrace{\left(\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)} h \right)}^{\text{This}\to g'(x)\text{ as }h\to0.} + g(x)\overbrace{\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h\right)}^{\text{This}\to f'(x)\text{ as }h\to0.}.
\end{align}
The continuity of differentiable functions is used to prove the part that says $f(x+h)\to f(x)$ as $h\to0$.

**My question is** whether it can be demonstrated that all proofs of the product rule must rely on this fact or something in some reasonable sense equivalent to it?

(Just how it would enter the proof of the product rule by logarithmic differentiation I haven't finished thinking through yet.)

**PS:** That I was momentarily guilty of a stupid mistake is what caused me to think of posting this here.  In proving the quotient rule, we have
$$
\frac{\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)} - \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} h = \frac{\left(\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)} h \right)g(x) - f(x)\left(\frac{g(x+h)- g(x)} h \right)}{g(x+h)g(x)}.
$$
Looking at the numerator and losing sight of the denominator, I thought: lo and behold! We don't need continuity of differentiable functions for this one.  Upon further cogitation, I realized what I'd missed.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, you can post the solution as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: @fonini : I am aware of that, and in fact I've done it several times.  But I haven't solved this one.

Comment: Sorry, I read your post too quickly.

Comment: *Technically* Leibniz didn't have to invoke continuity when he proved the product rule, but then again, his methods had their own issues...

Answer (score 1):

You are using a much stronger fact, both $f$ and $g$ are, per assumption, differentiable in $x$ and thus $$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+o_f(h)$$ and $$g(x+h)=g(x)+hg'(x)+o_g(h).$$ 
Which means that the functions must be automatically continuous in $x$.

---

One can of course also directly use those Weierstrass decompositions to prove the product rule,
$$
f(x+h)g(x+h)=f(x)g(x)+h(f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x))+(h^2f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)o_g(h)+g(x)o_g(h))
$$
where the last term is again of size $o(h)$.

---

For the inverse function and thus the quotient rule one can similarly compute
$$
\frac1{g(x+h)}=\frac1{g(x)+hg'(x)+o_g(h)}=\frac{g(x)-hg'(x)}{g(x)^2+o(h)}=\frac1{g(x)}-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}+o(h)
$$
with application of binomial formulas resp. geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\st}{\operatorname{st}}$I don't know if this counts, but the following is the approach taken by Keisler's [Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html). The important thing to note here is that $\st()$ denotes the standard, or non-infinitesimal part of a number, and $\st(a \cdot b) = \st(a) \cdot \st(b)$. Also note that the derivative of a function is defined in this case as $$f'(x) = \frac{df}{dx} = \st\left(\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}\right)$$

Where $\Delta x$ is infinitesimal.

**Proof of the Product Rule.**

Let $y = uv$, then $y + dy = (u + \Delta u)(v + \Delta v) = uv + u \ \Delta v + v \ \Delta u + \Delta u \ \Delta v$, or $$\Delta y = u \ \Delta v + v \ \Delta u + \Delta u \ \Delta v$$

(since $y = uv$). Then $$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{u \ \Delta v + v \ \Delta u + \Delta u \ \Delta v}{\Delta x} = u \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x} + v \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \Delta u \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}$$

Taking the standard part, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = u \frac{dv}{dx} + v\frac{du}{dx} + 0$$

Or just $$\frac{d}{dx}[u v] = u \frac{dv}{dx} + v \frac{du}{dx}$$

Maybe this wasn't *exactly* what you were looking for, but this *is* a proof of the product rule without appealing to continuity (in fact, continuity isn't even discussed until the next chapter). Of course, this is if you're comfortable with nonstandard analysis. I await other answers that address your question in terms of standard analysis.

Comment: How do we know the standard part of $\Delta u$ is $0$?  Isn't that continuity of $u$ as a function of $x$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: By definition the standard part is the non-infinitesimal part of a number, thus the standard part of an infinitesimal is $0$, and $\Delta u$ is an infinitesimal (that is, if I understand the author correctly). To see this, write $\Delta u$ as $0 + \Delta u$.

Comment: You say $\Delta u$ is an infinitesimal.  But that would be true only if $u$ is continuous as a function of $x$. ${}\qquad{}$